How to Implement Certificate-Based Authentication in Playwright js/ts?
I am working on authenticating user login, and I need to automate the test that implement certificate-based authentication using Playwright js/ts. Specifically, I want to ensure that users are authenticated based on the certificates installed in their system and need to select the certificate from the list.
Select certificate from list
How can I set up Playwright to handle certificate-based authentication? What are the steps or configurations required to make this work?

Does this help? https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/1799#issuecomment-2247406174

Please share a [mcve]. Without a page and some code, there's no easy way to help here.
